# Post-processing the heatmap in python or ImageMagick

Tags: python, python-2.7, imagemagick, heatmap

How could I make this **heatmap look more clear** without the blurred effect. How could I sharpen it Python (or ImageMagick)? also, *how could I **get a pixel-grid** on the background?*

[image]

Here is what I used to get the current image:

```
maxsize = (1030, 2056)
for i in range(1,334,1):
    img = Image.open('C:Desktop/Img/image'+'_'+ str(i)+'.png')
    img = img.resize(maxsize, Image.BICUBIC)
    img.save('C:/Desktop/Res/img'+'_'+ str(i)+'.png', dpi = (7040,7040))
```

I also tried in ImageMagick (but that did not help much, atleast looking visually):

```
magick img_244.png -sharpen 0x3 out.png
```

Thank you very much in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ImageMagick (and also OpenCV/python) you can use kmeans to process your image. I have a bash unix shell script for ImageMagick that does that.

```
kmeans -n 7 -m 5 g4Zwf.png result7.png
```

where n is the number of colors and m is the maximum number of iterations.

[image]

Then you can use my script, grid, to draw lines (or use ImageMagick directly) to draw lines. Using my script, grid with 100 pixel spacing gives:

```
grid -s 100,100 -c white result7.png result7g100.png
```

[image]

My scripts are at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.html

For OpenCV/Python, see http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_ml/py_kmeans/py_kmeans_opencv/py_kmeans_opencv.html and [How to write lines and grid on image in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18044485/how-to-write-lines-and-grid-on-image-in-python)

OpenCV/Python also has expectation maximization that may perform better on your color processing than kmeans. See [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation–maximization_algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm) 
and 
[Maximum likelihood pixel classification in python opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40553596/maximum-likelihood-pixel-classification-in-python-opencv)

Answer (score 0):

What module did you import as is `Image`? What you need is a nearest neighbor interpolation, not bicubic [interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation). Probably something like

```
img = img.resize(maxsize, Image.INTER_NEAREST)
```

Comment: I used PIL (import Image). I think the nearest neighbour interpolation is too big an interpolation and the size of the pixel (if i can say) is too huge. As a result, the level of smoothness that we want to see is not obtained. Would there be an alternative? I used this site for the reference: https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/code/216637/resize-an-image-python

Comment: Your original image doesn't contain more information than you see in the nearest neighbor "interpolation". I fear I cannot help you more than just referring to the different [interpolation methods in PIL](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize). Maybe one of them leads to something close to your desired appearance. And you could change the colormap, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965417/how-to-convert-numpy-array-to-pil-image-applying-matplotlib-colormap) for how to use matplotlib colormaps with PIL.

Comment: I would agree with LUB. If you have a very small original set of data and are trying to expand, then by using -resize, you are blurring it due to the pixel interpolation. All I did above was to try to separate it into unique colors. If you want to enlarge, you should either use -scale in ImageMagick or try -filter carton -resize, which might give you a bit sharper result depending upon how much enlargement you have. But LUB is correct. You do not get more information than from pixel replication using -scale.